# For which $p \in (0, +\infty)$ is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1/p} \leq 1\}$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

### For which $p \in (0, +\infty)$ is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1/p} \leq 1\}$ convex?

I should be able to answer this question just using the definition of a convex set:

> *A set $S$ is said to be **convex** if for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$, and every $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have that $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \in S$.*

That was easy to see for $p=1$, but I have no clue how to prove it in a more general way.

Comment: Have you tried just sketching this set for the simplest cases:
1. $n = 2, p = 1/2$
2. $n = 2, p = 1$
3. $n = 2, p = 2$
4. $n = 3, p = 1$?

Comment: @avs sketching it seems that the set is convex for $p \in [1, +\infty]$.

Comment: Good.  How does the set look for case 3 that I listed?